# Create a Expression in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

My LINQ query is like the below code.

```
 var data2 = data.Where(c => String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", c.OrderDate) == "07/04/1996");
```

I need to customize the predicate for formatted column in the below expression. I need to write the Expression for predicate and filter the data based on format. please check below code.

```
pred =Expression.Equal(membertype, Expression.Constant(value, type));
lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicate, paramExpression);
source.Where(paramExpression, predicate);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why does this **need** to be converted? Does it not work? Besides, it is already a lambda expression...

Comment: This is already a lambda expression. Go through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions)

Comment: I have modified the query to understandable one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that creates the `.Where` dynamically.

```
static void DynamicWhereBuilder() {
  var datas = new Data[] {
    new Data { OrderDate  = "07/04/1996"},
    new Data { OrderDate  = "07/04/1990"},
    new Data { OrderDate  = "07/04/2001"},
    new Data { OrderDate  = "2012/04/07"}
  };
  IQueryable<Data> queryableData = datas.AsQueryable<Data>();

  var formatConstant = Expression.Constant("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", typeof(string));
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Data), "dataArg");
  var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "OrderDate");

  var left = Expression.Call(property, typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) }), formatConstant, property);
  var right = Expression.Constant("07/04/2001", typeof(string));

  var equal = Expression.Equal(left, right);
  var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
    queryableData.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Data, bool>>(equal, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
  var results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<Data>(whereCallExpression); // returns the object with OrderDate = "07/04/2001"
}
```

Comment: I am not able to run your code, if do so the below exception is thrown
Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: instance

Comment: Can't expect people to help you if you're not providing detailed information. How are you running the code and where exactly does the exception happen?